# Google Analytics: Event funnel with multiple events per session

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

**How can we track bounce rates for event funnels with Google Analytics if multiple events occur per session?**

As we don’t have an ecommerce app (Web, iPad and Android), but an app where users follow the same process multiple times (e.g. 100 times per session), we want to see how often and where they drop out of the funnel per session.As each goal in a funnel is only achievable once per session, so we need to work around that. How can we track the bounce rates based on all events per session?

Example: Order of events in the funnel: A -> B -> C -> D

Event flow for one user: A - B - C - A - B - C - D (goal achieved) - A - A - A - B - C - ...

Funnel should look like: A (5 events, drop out 40%=2 events) -> B (3 events, drop out 0%=0 events) -> C (3 events, drop out 66%=2 events) -> D (1 event, goal achieved)

Now it looks like: A (1 session, drop out 0%) -> B (1 session, drop out 0%) ….

I found that there is an event flow report in GA, but I’m not sure whether that would suit my purpose. Does anybody have any ideas? And if it’s really impossible with GA does anybody know any alternative (free) tools?

Thanks a lot! Lotta

Comment: Funnels in GA work by tracking the maximum stage for each user.  It doesn't track number of times each stage was hit, nor even if a stage were hit at all.   If a stage is skipped, GA "backfills", or assumes they must have hit it.   All GA cares about is how far along the chain they got.

Comment: I would suggest to track those events via analytics-events, put those data automatically into a spreadsheet and build filters and segments for the different cases. You can build your funnel visualization within the spreadsheet then. Mucho trabajo - but it will be gooooood data then. :-)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, as you said, [Google Analytics will track any Goal Conversion once per session](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2679221?hl=en). There is no workaround in there.

You could use [Google Analytics Ecommerce plugin to get conversion funnels](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hmZSoI_xKVA) (no limit per session) but it is not the best approach to this problem. Don't forget that Analytics has [collection limits](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/limits-quotas?hl=en).

I will definitely look for a software that can provide **workflows analysis**. I've been using [this tool](http://www.connectif.ai) for a time, maybe you can try it.

[image]